# Mapping two lists of characters to make them reciprocal

Tags: c#, list

I have a string list with 676 pairs of letters, and no repeats: (**AA, AB, AC...ZW, ZX, ZZ**)

I have a second string list with the same 676 pairs but they are now shuffled: (**GH,KI,RT...WE,SD,BB**)

I need to map each element on both lists in such a way that they will be reciprocal but not the same(can't have BB=BB, etc..)

```
AA = GH
AB = KI
AC = RT
.
.
GH = AA
.
.
KI = AB
.
.
RT = AC
```

For each letter group(A*,B*,C*...) only one mapped pair can begin with the same letter. (for example you can have CD=CH, DH=DE, but not CD=CH, CE=CY...)

I'm stuck on how to go through each element( maybe shuffling the second list) and make sure they match eachother on both lists. Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You say 'only one mapped pair can begin with the same letter', but what about pairs that don't begin with the same letter on both sides? You can have as many of those as you like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Take just the first list. In addition, create a boolean array 26 entries long, one for each alphabetical character. This will be used to indicate if a same-letter pair for that character has been used yet or not. Also, make a map of strings to strings.

2) Pick two elements from the list at random.

3) If it is an OK pair (not the same entry twice, didn't pick a same character starting pair we've already done) add both directions to the map + if it's a same character starting pair flag its character entry in the boolean array.

4) If the list is now empty, go to 5). If we've exceeded a magic number of attempts (2000 or 3000 for example) go back to 1) and start again. Else go to 2). (This is because sometimes we may end up with an unsolvable ending, such as only C starting entries when we already have a C starting pair and thus can't add more)

5) Interpret the map as a list of `string,string` tuples, sort it by the first string alphabetically, and unzip each tuple into two lists. The first list will be list A, the second list will be list B. You will have only perfect reciprocals and no more than one same letter pair for any letter.

Comment: Thank you Patashu, your solution solved the problem! Now I see how to do it. Much simpler than what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int count = l1.Count;
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    string s1 = l1(i);
    string s2 = l2(i);

    if (!s1.Equals(s2)) {
        if (!s1[0].Equals(s2[0])) {
            dict.Add(s1, s2);
        } else {
                //magicMethod();
                }
    } else {
        //magicMethod();
    }
}
```

l1 and l2 being your lists.

Comment: Whatever OP wants it to do when the values are equal... His question did not specify that part...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that two list has the same length. You can implement like this :

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyList.ElementAt(i), valueList.ElementAt(i));
}
```

Comment: How does this ensure 'they will be reciprocal but not the same'?